# Is there a way to take a key from one dictionary and add it to another?

Tags: python, dictionary, asynchronous, key-value

My goal is to take a key from one dictionary which holds lots of keys and values, and add the key to an empty dictionary. The key is stored in a variable name called "bossname" all of the keys in that dictionary have the same variable name so that I can use it in other places. The value to all of the keys in the boss_list dictionary is stored in "min"

```
boss_list = {
"test": 20,
"hi": 3,
"170": 80,
}

boss_timers_dict = {}

    async def boss_down(bossname, min):
    due_at = int(time.time()+(min))
    hm_from_now = int(due_at) - int(time.time())
    due_in_six = int(due_at) - int(time.time() + int(6))
    print("timed msg here...")

    for hm_from_now in range(due_at):

        if hm_from_now == min:
            #This is where my question is about
            if bossname in boss_list:
                boss_timers_dict.update([bossname])

            coro = asyncio.sleep(1)
            await coro
            del boss_timers_dict[bossname]
            break
```

What I expected to happen was for the "bossname" to be taken from the boss_list dictionary and added to the empty boss_timers_dict dictionary. I have tried doing

```
if bossname in boss_list:
    boss_timers_dict.update(bossname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign the contents of `bossname` to `boss_timers_dict`, just do:

```
if bossname in boss_list:
    boss_timers_dict = boss_list[bossname]
```

Suppose the `boss_list` dictionary have this structure, and the `bossman` variable contains the string `"bossman"`:

```
{'bossname': {k1: i1, k2: i2, ....}, key2: value 2}
```

By doing that above, the `boss_timers_dict` should now contain:

```
{k1: i1, k2: i2, ....}
```

But if you want the new dict to have the key `bossname` that containing the `boss_list['bossname']`, just do :

```
if 'bossname' in boss_list:
    boss_timers_dict['bossname'] = boss_list['bossname']
```

Therefore, the `boss_timers_dict` should now contain

```
{'bossname': {k1: i1, k2: i2, ....}}
```

Comment: @DhanaD. That was already very helpful, do you know of a way to only grab the key, and not the value as well? 
`boss_timers_dict.update(test=hm_from_now)` This was my original code where I was hard coding in "Test" from the other dictionary. So the goal is to keep the hm_from_now value the same, but not have to hard code in all of the keys from the other dictionary.

Comment: If you want to grab all keys exist in the dictionary, just use `.keys()`